# Error while installing sampledata Magento 2.4

Tags: sample-data, magento2.4

I have setup the Magento 2.4 on Windows 10.
I have run these commands to install the sampledata:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy   - Working 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade   - Error
```

**Error: **Unable to apply data patch Magento\CatalogSampleData\Setup\Patch\Data\InstallCatalogSampleData for module Magento_CatalogSampleData. Original exception message: Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.****

For clarification see attached screenshot:
[image]

**Note- I am getting this error only in Magento2.4 version**

Comment: Try to install sample data Manually, Here is the link for sample data https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data Let me know if it's help.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the DB connection to a new DB then try to delete composer.lock and run `composer install`, then `bin/magento setup:upgrade`. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link I think it has your answer.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25294

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Github Issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30685) describing the problem. It was fixed for the next develop version of 2.4 in October 2020.

Here is the [specific PR](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/30928) that was accepted into the 2.4 release branch.

I haven't yet found a workaround other than "it's fixed in the next version".

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in the **CustomerSampleData** module.
I temporarily resolved this in v2.3.6 by commenting out the following line:

```
$this->customerSetup->install(['Magento_CustomerSampleData::fixtures/customer_profile.csv']);
```

at: **vendor/magento/module-customer-sample-data/Setup/Installer.php**

Final Code:

```
public function install()
{
   //$this->customerSetup->install(['Magento_CustomerSampleData::fixtures/customer_profile.csv']);
}
```

Seems to be something funky in the CSV.
Re-run setup-upgrade and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I did had such a problem and recovered by run command
`php bin/magento sampledata:remove`
after upgrade run normally

Comment: But this command removes sample data installed.  This is not fix for the issue. We need smaple data in magento 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug for Magento 2.4 versions. Found this solution:

bin/magento module:uninstall --remove-data --clear-static-content Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData Magento_SalesRuleSampleData

But not a recommended solution. As it does not contain complete sample data information.

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same error and invested four days rectifying it.

I also tried the above solution, i.e., commenting the line under install function from vendor/magento/module catalogue rule sample data/setup/installer.php and vendor/magento/module sales rule sample data/setup/installer.php. It too worked, but only temporarily. Because after following the above procedure, you cannot see the products from your Magento homepage, just banners only visible to you.

The real problem is that there is no sufficient space to deploy the sample data. Clear more than 4GB of space on your system and try it. It will work.